# mysqli_fetch_assoc() - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Como funciona a função **mysqli_fetch_assoc**?
Exemplo, se eu usar ela em uma função como está abaixo em PHP. O que ela faz?

```
function buscar_tarefas($conexao){
    $sqlBusca = "SELECT * FROM tarefas";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sqlBusca);
    $tarefas = array();
    while($tarefa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        $tarefas[] = $tarefa;
    }
    return $tarefas;
}
```

Comment: É chato, sim, mas precisamos perguntar: você pesquisou na [documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)? Ficou com dúvida em alguma parte específica? O que realmente não entendeu da função?

Comment: minha dúvida foi o retorno da função, não entendi como ela funciona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` retorna um array com os resultados do banco, mas os índices desse array vão ser representados pelo nome da coluna, por exemplo:

Em uma tabela temos as colunas nome, email, e telefone e o resultado de uma busca nessa tabela vai ser atribuido a variavel `$res`.

Em vez de você acessar o dado utilizando `$res[0]`, `$res[1]` e `$res[2]`, você vai acessar utilizando `$res['nome']`, `$res['email']` e `$res['telefone']`.